# PHP Paypal IPN Dispute handling

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a Paypal IPN that handles all my payments, creates accounts in the database, etc. When it comes to disputes, it can check when one is opened and adds a row for the dispute with transaction id, amount, etc. My problem is I don't know if there's a way to check if the dispute is closed, and if it is won/lost. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

IPN has `transaction_type` parameter which can contain different variables and this is how you know what is happening.

In your case you check `transaction_type` to be `adjustment` and if it is you can see `case_type` to check if it is a disput or refund.

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference#id091EBC0E05Z